# How do we figure out all the mappings which are using a oracle package in it?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I there a way to figure out all the mappings which are using an oracle package in it? rather than opening each and every mapping and searching for the stored procedure transformation and checking its contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this sql in informatica metadata repository -

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
        widat.attr_value  stored_prc_name  ,
        all_map.mapping_name,
        all_map.subject_area folder_name
FROM
        rep_all_mappings all_map,
        rep_widget_inst  wid    ,
        opb_widget_attr  widat
WHERE
        all_map.mapping_id=wid.mapping_id
AND     wid.widget_id=widat.widget_id
AND     widat.widget_type=wid.widget_type
AND     wid.widget_type   =6  
AND     widat.attr_id=1`
```